# Analytical Function Max and nested case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, max

*Edit
  I have the below output table

```
ID    cl_id   start_dt    end_dt    as_dt    pc_id  max_role  max_pc_id  first_as_DT 
1      101     1/31/18    2/2/18    6/13/14    5245   red       (null)
1      101     1/31/18    2/2/18    1/10/18   (null)  red       (null)
1      101     1/31/18    2/2/18    2/1/18     1457   red       (null)
1      101     1/31/18    2/2/18    2/2/18    (null)  red       (null)
```

Query:

```
      SELECT *

       ,CASE 
        WHEN AS_DT < START_DT AND MAX_ROLE = 'RED' AND MAX_PC_ID IS NOT NULL THEN START_DT
        WHEN A_DT BETWEEN START_DT AND NVL(END_DT,SYSDATE) AND ROLE = 'RED' AND PC_ID IS NOT NULL 
        THEN MIN(AS_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY CL_ID ORDER BY CL_ID ,AS_DT)
        ELSE ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,200) --TESTING PURPOSES
        END FIRST_ASSGN_DT

       FROM TABLEA
```

OUTPUT:

```
FIRST_AS_DT
10/7/2034
10/7/2034
6/16/14  
10/7/2034
```

expecting results of not 6/16/14 but 2/1/18 because that the min date that is between start and end date

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't follow the question.  Your sample data has three rows, but the result set had one.

Comment: I could get answer with rank function but I'll leave open for other suggestions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's correct. I only want one row to show per clt_id

Comment: Can you please add your full query what you tried with rank and also what is the output you are expecting and more sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [KEEP DENSE RANK FIRST / LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) functions.

```
SELECT Id , clt_ID  ,  start_dt   , End_dt,
       max( a_date ) 
            KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY 
                  case when ROLE = 'RED' AND a_date < start_dt then a_date end ) 
       As last_a_date_before_Start_dt,
       max(  userid  ) 
            KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY 
                  case when ROLE = 'RED' AND a_date < start_dt then a_date end ) 
       As USERID
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id,  clt_ID  ,  start_dt  ,  End_dt
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2dbbb/13

```
| ID | CLT_ID |              START_DT |                END_DT | LAST_A_DATE_BEFORE_START_DT | USERID |
|----|--------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------------|--------|
|  1 |    101 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2017-02-01 00:00:00.0 |       2017-12-30 00:00:00.0 |    525 |
```